# functor doesn't work in c++

Tags: c++, functor

I have a Vector class(not the one built in). I want to write a built in function that I can traverse the Vector class.
The vector class is defined in this way:

```
template <typename T> class Vector{int _size; int _capicity ; T* _elem;
   /(protected and public functions/};
```

Then I write a public function traverse:

```
template <typename T> template <typename VST> 
void Vector<T>::traverse ( VST& visit ) 
{ for ( int i = 0; i < _size; i++ ) visit ( _elem[i] ); }
//visit here represent some action that I am gonna perform on the elements
```

To test the code:
I write a functor to perform _elem[i]++ on every elements of the vector class.

```
template <typename T>
struct Increase 
  {virtual void operator() ( T& e ) { e++; }  };
```

In the main program, I write a function:

```
template <typename T>
void increase ( Vector<T> & V )
 {  V.traverse ( Increase<T>() );  }
```

Note: this function is different from the Increase function, which is a functor.

Here is how I test my program:

```
 Vector<int> c={1,2,3,4,5}; //initialize my vector class
 increase(c);
```

It returns error message:

```
 no match function for call to 'traverse'.
```

I figure out it might have something to do with the way I declare traverse.

```
void Vector<T>::traverse ( VST& visit );
V.traverse ( Increase<T>() );//this is the way I called this function.
```

Then I remove the "&" here and use VST visit and this time it works but I still have a big problem that I don't know why I can't use VST& visit as the variable of the traverse function.

It seems fine for me to pass by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `VST` by value in the traverse function. Currently, you passing an r-value object which can be accepted by only `const-reference`(const T&) or `r-value reference` (T&&) [which becomes universal reference with template].

```
template <typename T> 
template <typename VST> 
void Vector<T>::traverse ( VST visit ) 
{ 
   for ( int i = 0; i < _size; i++ ) visit ( _elem[i] ); 
}
```

To make it work by reference, first create an `l-value` instance of the functor and then call `traverse`.

```
template <typename T>
void increase ( Vector<T> & V )
{  
   Increase<T> inc;
   V.traverse ( inc );  
}
```

But prefer passing it by value if you can. STL takes functor by value. Also, you shouldn't take by `const-reference` as well, because then you will have to make your `operator()` `const` as well

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure is that because I shouldn't pass a functor in this way? Because in my function increase, I also passing an r-value object to a l-value reference.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. The issue you were seeing was because you were passing a temporary (r-value) to a function which accepts only l-value reference. This binding does not work. Temporaries can only be bound by either taking by value or by const-reference or by r-value reference (in C++11 only)

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand what's the problem in my code. I shouldn't try to pass a temporary(Increase<T>()) to a l-value reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to pass a temporary, `Increase<T>()`, as a non-const reference parameter. C++ only allows temporaries to bind to const reference parameters (or r-value reference parameters).

The solution is to either pass by value, or declare an `Increase<T>` local variable and pass it into `V.traverse()`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the key to my problem is temporary r-value.